# LINQ query to MVC Viewmodel multiple tables and lists

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to make one query to hit the database for 5 different tables to send to my view in one viewmodel. Here are my data classes.

```
public partial class Table_Parts_Warehouse
{
    public int CQPN { get; set; }
    public int CATEGORY { get; set; }
    public int SUBCATEGORY { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public int QTY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MINSTK { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MAXSTK { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> COST { get; set; }
}

public partial class Table_Parts_Order
{
    public int ORDERID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATE { get; set; }
    public bool STATUS { get; set; }
    public string PONO { get; set; }
    public string INVOICENO { get; set; }
    public string QUOTENO { get; set; }
    public int COMPANYID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> COST { get; set; }
}

public partial class Table_Parts_OrderPart
{
    public int ORDERPARTID { get; set; }
    public int ORDERID { get; set; }
    public int CQPN { get; set; }
    public int ORDERQTY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RECVQTY { get; set; }
    public string PARTNO { get; set; }
}

public partial class Table_Parts_Vendor
{
    public int COMPANYID { get; set; }
    public string PHONENO { get; set; }
    public string COMPANYNAME { get; set; }
}

public partial class Table_Parts_Part
{
    public int PARTID { get; set; }
    public int CQPN { get; set; }
    public string PARTNO { get; set; }
    public decimal COST { get; set; }
    public int COMPANYID { get; set; }
    public int QTY { get; set; }
}
```

My viewmodel class is here, all of these classes, the order class is a single order entry but the rest are all lists for the associated parts and data for that order.

```
public class OrderDetailsViewModel
{
    public Table_Parts_Order tb_parts_order { get; set; }
    public List<Table_Parts_OrderPart> tb_parts_orderpart { get; set; }
    public List<Table_Parts_Vendor> tb_parts_vendor { get; set; }
    public List<Table_Parts_Warehouse> tb_parts_warehouse { get; set; }
    public List<Table_Parts_Part> tb_parts_part { get; set; }
}
```

In my view controller, I am trying to do 1 query for all of this and select them in one go.  I can do this each individually with the same query and select the table and then .ToList() which works fine, but I am hitting the database 5 times instead of once.  Need help to select lists within this query.

```
public ActionResult PartsOrderDetails(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);


    OrderDetailsViewModel vm = new OrderDetailsViewModel();

    vm = (from a in db.Table_Parts_Warehouse
              join b in db.Table_Parts_OrderPart
              on a.CQPN equals b.CQPN
              join c in db.Table_Parts_Part
              on b.PARTNO equals c.PARTNO
              join d in db.Table_Parts_Vendor
              on c.COMPANYID equals d.COMPANYID
              join e in db.Table_Parts_Order
              on b.ORDERID equals e.ORDERID
              orderby a.CQPN ascending
              where b.ORDERID == id
              select new OrderDetailsViewModel
              {
                  tb_parts_order = e,
                  tb_parts_orderpart = b, //(.ToList)
                  tb_parts_vendor = d, //(.ToList)
                  tb_parts_warehouse = a, //(.ToList)
                  tb_parts_part = c //(.ToList)
              });

    return View(vm);

}
```

This obviously does not work because I cannot get lists like this.  I have seen where people make another query in select new but I dont want to repeat the query 5 times.  Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a model for every table.  This will make what you are trying to do a bit harder.  Also it is a good practice to leave your controller clean and queries should be done in a separate service class

Comment: I am sorry but I don't really know what you mean.  I need to display the details of the order and show the actual order with a table of all the associated ordered parts and vendor and other details from warehouse table and part table.  I need all this information and so I figured I should get all the data and send it via a viewmodel.  I can use JS and get the data using ajax but then again I am hitting the database multiple times.  Just trying to improve performance.

Comment: **This obviously does not work because I cannot get lists like this** Can you elaborate a little bit on this ? Why do you think so ?

Comment: Just gave you a snippet of my project.  I think you should pursue something like that

Comment: Thank you EasyE, I have only used this entity database linq queries and haven't dove into sqlconnection.  I guess the main problem I'm having is that I have 1 item that is a single entry and 4 other items that are lists in my view model.  Instead of using the whole table, I could use just the data I will be displaying which may be a good idea.  But I will still have the same problem where order is single entry and all the parts are a list. Really I am just asking how to use my query and in the select new add code that allows me to grab these tables as lists.

Comment: Is there a way to just do the query as a var and then be able to say vm.tb_parts_orderparts = query.select(tb_parts_orderparts).ToList()? And I could do this for each table?

Comment: I have tried to do it like that but I had more problems debugging bad data that came back.  I suggest you look into "petapoco", this may be where you would like to go

Comment: Yea that definitely seems like an option. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a code snippet from a previous project I had.  You can get a good idea from this example.  It is good practice to not do querying in your controller for debugging purposes.  I created a service class.

**Service class**

```
   public static List<RetrivalQueryModel> GetPartner()
    {
        List<RetrivalQueryModel> partnerList = new List<RetrivalQueryModel>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_constring))
        {
            StringBuilder sqlCommandBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            sqlCommandBuilder.Append("SELECT Partner.PartnerId, (Staff.Forename+ ','+Staff.Surname) AS Name FROM tblpartner Partner JOIN tblstaff Staff ON Staff.StaffId = Partner.StaffId Where Partner.Suspended = 0 ORDER BY Staff.Forename , Staff.Surname "); //will search only for active partners, take away Partner.Suspended to show all
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandBuilder.ToString(), connection);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RetrivalQueryModel partner = new RetrivalQueryModel();
                        partner.Partner = reader.GetString(1);
                        partner.PartnerId = reader.GetInt32(0);

                        partnerList.Add(partner);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Error(ex);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex);
            }
        }
        return partnerList;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetPartnerList()
    {
        List<RetrivalQueryModel> rtnList = PMService.GetPartner();
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = rtnList;
        result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        return result;
    }
```

**Model**

```
namespace EngagementRetrival.Models
{
public class RetrivalQueryModel
{
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    public int JobStatusID { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public int MarketId { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public string Partner { get; set; }
    public int PartnerId { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who cares, I figured this out.  Pretty easy actually.  Just don't try to do it within your linq query using select new OrderDetailsViewModel.  Just grab the query as a list, iterate through them and add to your lists.

```
public ActionResult PartsOrderDetails(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    OrderDetailsViewModel vm = new OrderDetailsViewModel();

    var query = (from a in db.Table_Parts_Warehouse
                 join b in db.Table_Parts_OrderPart
                 on a.CQPN equals b.CQPN
                 join c in db.Table_Parts_Part
                 on b.PARTNO equals c.PARTNO
                 join d in db.Table_Parts_Vendor
                 on c.COMPANYID equals d.COMPANYID
                 orderby a.CQPN ascending
                 where b.ORDERID == id
                 select new
                 {
                     tb_parts_orderpart = b,
                     tb_parts_vendor = d,
                     tb_parts_warehouse = a,
                     tb_parts_part = c
                 }).ToList();

    vm.tb_parts_order = db.Table_Parts_Order.Find(id);
    vm.tb_parts_orderpart = new List<Table_Parts_OrderPart>();
    vm.tb_parts_part = new List<Table_Parts_Part>();
    vm.tb_parts_vendor = new List<Table_Parts_Vendor>();
    vm.tb_parts_warehouse = new List<Table_Parts_Warehouse>();

    for (int i = 0; i < query.Count(); i++)
    {
        vm.tb_parts_orderpart.Add(query[i].tb_parts_orderpart);
        vm.tb_parts_part.Add(query[i].tb_parts_part);
        vm.tb_parts_vendor.Add(query[i].tb_parts_vendor);
        vm.tb_parts_warehouse.Add(query[i].tb_parts_warehouse);
    }

   return View(vm);
}
```